# Prove $S$ is linearly dependent if and only if some of its vectors is spanned by the others

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, notation

I was requested to show $S$ is linearly dependent if and only if $\alpha_i \in S$ is in the span of $S' = \{\alpha \in V| \alpha \neq \alpha _i\}$. More specifically, the problem was phrased as follows:

> Prove that a set of vectors $\{ \alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n   \}$ is LD if and only if some of its vectors is spanned by the others. In other words, if and only if there is some $1 \leq i \leq n$ such that $\alpha_i \in <v_1, ..., v_{i-1}, v_{i+1}, ..., v_n>$.

I'm very new to linear algebra and was wondering whether my proof is correct. I'm also concerned about my use of sub- and super-scripts in the summation symbol $\sum$. Here is what I did.

---

**Preliminary definitions:** Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{K}$ and $S = \{\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n \}$ a set where $\alpha_j \in V$ for any $j$.

$\textbf{I} ~ (\implies)$ Let $S$ be linearly dependent. Then there is a non-trivial combination of scalars $x_1, ..., x_n \in \mathbb{K}$ such that

\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{k=1}^n x_k\alpha_k = 0
\end{equation*}

This implies

\begin{align*}
    &\sum_{k\neq i}^n x_k\alpha_k + x_i \alpha_i= 0 \\
    &\sum_{k\neq i}^n x_k\alpha_k = -x_i\alpha_i \\
    -&\sum_{k\neq i}^n \frac{x_k}{x_i}\alpha_k = \alpha_i
\end{align*}

for any $i \in [1, n]$. Notice that $\frac{x_k}{x_i} \in \mathbb{K}$ is well-defined if we assume $x_i \neq 0$. This assumption is justified because $x_i$ might be *any* of the scalars $x_1, ..., x_n$, which are not all null by assumption of linear dependence of $S$. Then our result proves $\alpha_i$ is in the span of $S' = \{\alpha \in V|\alpha \neq \alpha_i\}$ or, equivalently, $\alpha_i \in <\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_{i-1}, \alpha_{i+1}, ..., \alpha_n>$.

$\textbf{II} (\impliedby)$ Assume

\begin{equation*}
    \alpha_i = \sum_{k \neq i}^{n - 1} x_i \alpha_i
\end{equation*}

for a non-trivial sequence of scalars $x_1, ..., x_{n-1}$. Then

\begin{align*}
    0 &= \sum_{k \neq i}^{n - 1} x_i \alpha_i + (-1)\alpha_i \\
    &=\sum_{k = 1}^{n} x_i \alpha_i 
\end{align*}

with $x_n = -1$. Then $S = \{ \alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n \}$ is LD.

---

As stated earlier, I would appreciate validation of the proof, on one hand, as well as validation of the notation $\sum_{k \neq i}^n$ as a way to indicate the sum of the natural numbers $1, ..., i -1, i+1, ..., n$.

Comment: This seems fine to me. Since you asked specifically about notation: I usually see $\sum_{k \ne i}$ rather than $\sum_{k \ne i}^n$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the conventional notation out!